# Designing pseudocode for loop assignment

Tags: loops, pseudocode

I'm in an intro to java class (first exposure to programming ever). My professor assigned this 
"Input positive numbers and display how many are in between 10 and 20"

We've learned loops and if else statements so far and can use both, either or neither of those.

My pseudocode looks like this so far. Please let me know if I'm on the right track.

```
BEGIN

   Input number from user

   WHILE number is positive

         IF (number >=10 && number >= 20)

         Add 1 to count

         END IF

      Input another number if user wants

      Display amount of numbers between 10 and 20

   END WHILE

END
```

Am I on the right track? I've been wrestling with this for a couple hours

Comment: looks right to me, yes. The only not so pretty part is that you have to write the "input" part in two places. You might want to move the "display" part out of the loop, depending on the specific assignment.

Comment: i dont think you can say `Display amount of numbers between 10 and 20` . That by itself is the goal is it not? 
`Display count`

Comment: I was thinking I would have to ask for an initial input to get the user into the loop. If it looks alright I'm going to start writing up some code and post it in a little bit for critique.

Comment: `Display count` should also be out of the `while`. You only want to display the count after all numbers have been entered. The problem is your while loop needs to eventually end. how about `WHILE number is positive integer` or `WHILE typeof(number) == integer && number > 0`
Then the loop will end when the user overwrites number to be `""`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to count numbers between 10 and 20 then.
This statement is wrong 
IF (number >=10 && number >= 20)
Correct statement is 
IF (number >=10 && number <= 20)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you're on the right track for sure. Here are my few suggestions:

BEGIN / END may or may not be necessary. Honestly, I wouldn't use them. But some people do. Pseudocode is kind of - different for everybody.

Use variables consistently, and use assigment operations still in your code.

By this I mean, `number = input from user` instead of `Input number from user` or `Input another number if user wants`.

You should define `counter = 0` before the while loop starts. Otherwise, you're incrementing a variable that isn't there.

IF / END IF might be a way to do it, but you could also use brackets or indentation to make the code more readable and mean the same thing.

Finally, about code correctness:

Did you want `>= 10` and `>= 20`? You probably meant `<= 20` because otherwise only values greater or equal to 20 would work. But aside from just the one sign, do you *want them to be greater/less than **or equal** to* the number? "In between" is vague, and might mean 11-19 or 10-20. It depends on how you frame the problem.

My final bit of input is, do you want to display the number every time the loop runs through? Or just after you enter a negative number and end the loop. If you want to display it only once, move it a line down. Otherwise, no big deal.

You're definitely on the right track and I wouldn't sweat it so much. Think of pseudocode as logical instructions. Flow through it very literally when you read it and when you write it, it's not about how it *looks* as to *how it works*.

I wish you a lot of luck, all the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode is always hard to correct but I think this would be much better

1) is positive is not a reasonable command, given that whether the input is numeric is unknown

2) initialize `count` to 0 before the while loop.

3) `number <= 20` not `number >= 20`

4) Move `display` out of the `while` loop

5) `Display count` because your current statement is literally the problem

6) `count += 1` is shorter and easier to read

7) we should get number in the while loop to ensure we stop when there is no input. something along the lines of `while input number from user` would stop in some languages once the input is blank. It will throw an error if the input cannot be coerced into a double. And it will stop when a negative is entered.

```
BEGIN

   Initialize count = 0
   WHILE number = input from user as double && number > 0  

         IF (number >=10 && number >= 20)

             count += 1

         END IF

   END WHILE
   Display count
END
```

Comment: If I move the display out of the while loop the while loops becomes infinite. How would I give the program instruction to display the count outside of the while loop?

Comment: the while loop would be infinite either way

Comment: Would I be better off using a for loop in this case?

Comment: A for loop would be for the case where you know how many user inputs there are. Since you do not you should use a while loop that stops when the user enters nothing, or some behavior you tell the user in advance, like entering negatives

Comment: In the pseudocode I wrote, the line where I define the while loop is supposed to set the condition where an input of nothing stops the loop or a negative number stops the loop, and then count is displayed

Comment: if you want the user to input positive numbers indefinitely, and display the count at each step, leave display inside the loop.

Comment: If you want to display count after all numbers have been entered, put display where I have